# UIWebView scrolls under navigation bar for text inputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I have a UINavigationController with an UIViewController in its stack. This view controller only shows one UIWebView that extends nicely under the UINavBar und UITabBar I have in my app. Great! Now if I tap an textarea input in this web view and the iPhone/iPad is in a landscape orientation the web view scrolls to a position where the cursor in that textarea is under the nav bar and so the user can't see what she is typing.
How can I fix this? Is this an iOS 8 bug or do I need to set a scroll inset manually for this?

Bests,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

OK it helps to set a contentInset to the scroll view (for me it was heightOfBar + heightOfStatusBar) if the keyboard shows and remove it again if the keyboard hides